# Map/route port from docker service to link using flask

Tags: python, docker, flask, routes

I'm trying something that is propably not intended and disagrees to the very purpose of the tools I'm using. However, I hope to get another perspective and approach to my problem.

**What I want to do:**
I have a complex software that runs in a docker container.
I wish to deploy it using flask. Whenever a user navigates to /user, I want the flask app to assign a user-id to the user, start a docker container and forward the user to user/user-id. The docker container exposed a random port that should then be mapped to user/user-id

**What I did so far:**

```
from flask import Flask, redirect
import docker
import requests
import uuid

# create flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
client = docker.from_env()

# initially build docker image
client.images.build(path='..')

# routing dictionary
user_routing_dict = {}


@app.route('/user')
def handle_new_user():

    # Create a new Docker container for the user
    container = client.containers.run(
        'complex software', 
        detach=True,
        ports={'8050/tcp': None}  # expose random port
    )
    
    # reload to be able to fetch port/host
    container.reload()
    
    # fetch port/host
    container_host = container.ports['8050/tcp'][0]['HostIp']
    container_port = container.ports['8050/tcp'][0]['HostPort']
    
    # register user port/link mapping
    user_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    user_routing_dict[user_id] = f'http://{container_host}:{container_port}/'

    return redirect(f'/user/{user_id}')


@app.route('/user/<string:user_id>')
def route_dash_app(user_id):
    if user_id in user_routing_dict:
        port = user_routing_dict[user_id]
        response = requests.get(port)
        return response.content, response.status_code
    else:
        return 'User ID/Service not found', 404


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8050, host='0.0.0.0')
```

**What does not meet my expectations, using my demo approach**
user/user-id is not mapped to the output of its according container. Only its content is requested, every time a user navigates to user/user-id. However I would rather want this link to "listen" to it. What I also do not want is to simply redirect user/user-id to localhost:user-port.